# loop device using too much storage

Tags: linux, centos, storage

This file (a loop device) `/dev/ploop28504p1` is using 80gb of my storage out of 90gb server.

I ran `lsof /dev/ploop28504p1` of that file

This is the portion of the result of `lsof /dev/ploop28504p1`:

```
COMMAND     PID               USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE  SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
init          1               root  cwd    DIR 182,456065      4096       2 /
init          1               root  rtd    DIR 182,456065      4096       2 /
init          1               root  txt    REG 182,456065    150352  396383 /sbin/init
init          1               root  mem    REG 182,456065     66432  413793 /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
init          1               root  mem    REG 182,456065   1924768  395978 /lib64/libc-2.12.so
init          1               root  mem    REG 182,456065     90912  413779 /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
init          1               root  mem    REG 182,456065     44472  413799 /lib64/librt-2.12.so
...
...
... around 5800 lines like this
...
...
node      32648             anuser  mem    REG 182,456065     20024  413788 /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
node      32648             anuser  mem    REG 182,456065    159312  409779 /lib64/ld-2.12.so
```

.

.

**If I run `umount /dev/ploop28504pl` I am getting this:**

```
umount: /: device is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
```

**If I run `mount`, I am getting this:**

```bsh
/dev/ploop28504p1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,barrier=1,data=ordered,balloon_ino=12)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
none on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,mode=755)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
none on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
```

**result of `df -h`**

```
Filesystem         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/ploop28504p1   89G   81G  4.3G  95% /
```

**update:**

**This is the result of `/etc/fstab`**

```bsh
none    /dev/pts        devpts  rw,gid=5,mode=620       0       0
none    /dev/shm        tmpfs   defaults                0       0
```

How can I manage that storage??

I am using centos 6 on my server.

Comment: it's a loop device and not a file

Comment: what should i do to get rid of this?

Comment: you can't do anything except unmount it because it's just a device. The real file lies somewhere else

Comment: @phuclv would this be any problem if I unmount this?

Comment: @phuclv I have edited the question. Have look please

Comment: "i don't know what lsof does"... Did you run it as root? Are you really sure that running it was a good idea? Look, the first thing to do- and YOU have to do this- is work out what that device is: it might turn out to be some sort of container and simply killing it would be a REALLY bad idea.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd well, I had some idea that `lsof` is not a bad command. Is there anything I can do to at least minimize the storage usage?

Comment: "Is there anything I can do" Find out what it is and why it's there. Then ask that question again. But don't go stabbing at things blindly, particularly as root: this is unix, and you'll break something.

Comment: @phuclv I am getting this when I run `mount /dev/ploop...`  -> `mount: according to mtab, /dev/ploop28504p1 is already mounted on /`

Comment: @HelloWorld just run `mount` without any parameters to see from where it's mounted. It's already mounted so obviously if you mount that again you'll get an error. Also post the content of `/etc/fstab`

Comment: @phuclv I have updated the question. please do check

Comment: If it's a loop device, perhaps the output of `losetup --list` (or `losetup -a` depending on the system) is relevant.